# JavaScript React setInterval "this" issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this, setinterval, self

I'm trying to learn React and I don't understand why this does not do anything when I try without an arrow function

```
componentDidMount() {
    var self = this
    this.timer = window.setInterval(function () {
        self.increment
    }, 1000)
}
```

Is the correct pattern `self.increment()`?

So why do I need the () when I don't need it in:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = window.setInterval(this.increment.bind(this),1000)
}
```

Comment: You could say that the `function` inside setInterval "steals" the `this` context ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: I would imagine you meant `self.increment()` ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*when I try without an arrow function*", there's no arrow function in your code?

Comment: @catgirlkelly That's incorrect, the `this` is correctly stored in a closure as `self`, when the function runs, `self` will point to the right object.

Comment: Are you saying that if you change this to use an arrow function, it works? I doubt that  It shouldn't matter at all because you are not using `this` from your `setInterval` callback. Prove me wrong with a [runnable example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). My guess? You removed `()` from `this.increment()` when you changed it from an arrow function to a regular function.

Comment: @Bergi because I was simply doing :
this.timer = setInterval(this.increment.bind(this), 1000)
And I tried with a regular function

Comment: @JuanMendes Are you saying that if you change this to use an arrow function, it works?
Yes it works: this.timer = setInterval(this.increment.bind(this), 1000)
Then the question might be: with the regular pattern why would I need the () when I don't need it with a fat arrow function?

Comment: @bob `this.increment.bind(this)` is not an arrow function

Comment: So when inserting my function directly I don't need to execute it:
`window.setInterval(this.increment.bind(this),1000)`




But when I insert it inside another function I need to execute it:
`window.setInterval(() => this.increment.bind(this)(), 1000)`

Comment: Uh, in both cases you are passing a function to `setInterval` that will execute the `increment` method. If you're passing a function that will *not* execute the method it won't work of course.

Answer (score 0):

You are not invoking self.increment, you are properly scoping `this` for your code to work. Maybe it appears it's not working because your interval's callback does not do anything :)

Also, here's a simpler version of your code, you could omit the .bind if your  function does not need to access your component's scope, but typically in react you'd want access to that:

```
this.timer = setInterval(this.increment.bind(this), 1000)
```

Comment: Correct answer but why mention `bind` at all? It's not really relevant.